# How to add 'New File' to the OS X Finder context menu?

Tags: macos, finder, context-menu

I am using a Mac--which is running OS X 10.10.3. I want to add a 'new file' button to the context menu--the menu that pops up when you right-click in a Finder window/on the desktop.

Comment: What kind of file? [Not that I think you can, it's just a bit vague as it stands]

Answer (score 3):

That can be done using Mac OS X native app Automator. Firstly, learn how to use it with that guide:

> http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-mac-right-click-menu/

Now, follow this tutorial to create the 'New File' button:

> [OS X Snow Leopard: Finder automator item for creating a new text file](https://superuser.com/questions/106943/os-x-snow-leopard-finder-automator-item-for-creating-a-new-text-file)

Use an empty file has your template; you may call it 'Untitled' for example. You can also assign a shortcut to it going to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services. That was my reference to this information:

> https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183269

I know that probably you wanted the button directly in the context menu, while Automator add it inside the Services tab. In order to do that, follow these instructions:

> http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/14/remove-services-contextual-menu-mac-os-x/

I think that's the best you can do. I hope these instructions are enough.

Comment: I saw that you found a duplicate question (and answer). Please mark that as a duplicate instead of referring/citing the other answer.